# Is there any "official" same-sex marriage in the Greek mythology?

Tags: greek

While the relationships in the Greek mythology are fluid, there is some notion of the marriage between Greek gods. My question is - is there any official same-sex marriage in the Greek mythology or some kind of relationships that are like marriage? Or maybe all same-sex relationships (e. g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LGBT_themes_in_classical_mythology) were for the pleasure of body and soul only?

I can not find such marriages in the internet and I guess that there are none simply because the ancient society has no similar notion of same-sex marriage in the human domain.

Comment: What counts as "official" marriage? I mean, I cannot recall any myth of gods having a wedding.

Comment: @Semaphore Of course there are Ancient Greek wedding myths! Examples: Thetis and Peleus, and Zeus and Hera.

Comment: @Mauricio Peleus was not a god; although Zeus's wedding is a good example my mind blanked on, thanks. Still, the question stands, what's the determinant here of "official"? Hesiod says Zeus married or made into wives a succession of goddesses (Metis, Themis, Eurynome, Demeter, Mnemosyne, and Leto) before Hera, and it's not evident that each involved a ceremony.

Comment: @Semaphore Peleus wasn’t but Thetis can still be considered a deity. Other gods that are considered “officially” married are Aphrodite and Hephaestus, Hades and Persefone, Poseidon and Anphitrite, and Eros and Psyche (who also had a wedding).

Comment: Stories with Hymenaios or any of the other Erotes might yield some results (I have no time to search due to a very busy schedule)